# problems with asp.net ajax and .net 4 TypeForAjax is undefined

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-4.0, ajax.net

After changing my target framework from 3.5 to 4, I had the symptoms and followed the steps described in http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2011/09/last-time-i-got-following-error-http.html

Now I get an error on one of my pages telling me that the ajax javascript representation for the page is undefined. does someone know what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Update: ok so it seems we're using an old version of ajax.net that isn't compatible with .net 4, so Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax does nothing. I've been searching for an updated version of the control but can only find one called ajaxpro. while this seems to be a new renamed version of ajax.net it's in a different namespace and the project has thousands of references. I would really like to find the latest ajax.net component released but haven't been able to get it all day. could someone please point me in the right direction?

Update: maybe the problem lies in my web.config, so here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sae_codelcoConnectionString" connectionString="server=192.168.4.142\sql2008r2;uid=sae_codelco;pwd=sae_codelco;database=testing_codelco" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="saeConnectionString" connectionString="server=192.168.4.142\sql2008r2;uid=sae_codelco;pwd=sae_codelco;database=testing_codelco" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="vb" maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="3000" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="aspnet" path="/" loginUrl="logon.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30"/>
    </authentication>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="1234567" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1234567"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
    <globalization culture="es-CL" uiCulture="es" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <location path="paginas/ordentrabajo/encuesta.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/ordentrabajo/encuesta_response_html.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/resp_remotas/tickets_abiertos.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="no_acceso.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/resp_remotas/cerrar_tickets.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/ticket/logon_tareas.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/ticket/tarea_ticket.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/encDinamica/encDinamica_basica_respuesta_persona.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="paginas/encDinamica/encDinamica_basica_respuesta_persona_display.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PathLocalSitio" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\"/>
    <add key="pathDocsTicket" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\Paginas\Docs\"/>
    <add key="pathDocumentos" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\Paginas\Documentos\Archivos\"/>
    <add key="Factor Semaforo Verde" value="50"/>
    <add key="Factor Semaforo Amarillo" value="75"/>
    <add key="Factor Semaforo Naranja" value="100"/>
    <add key="Factor Semaforo Rojo" value="150"/>
    <add key="Factor Semaforo Morado" value="200"/>
    <add key="Filtros Upload" value="exe,bat,dll,msi"/>
    <add key="Filtros Upload Mail" value="gif,jpg,jpeg"/>
    <add key="Server_Smtp" value="choclio.mosaq.com"/>
    <add key="Server_Smtp_Autenticar" value="1"/>
    <add key="Server_Smtp_Login" value="wquiroz"/>
    <add key="Server_Smtp_Password" value="rmQgGN34"/>
    <add key="from_mail" value="ialvarez@mosaq.com"/>
    <add key="DictionaryFolder" value="Paginas\NetSpell\dic"/>
    <add key="pathDocsAnalisisIPC" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\documentos\AnalisisIPC\"/>
    <add key="pathDocsMailsCRM" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\CRM\AdjuntosMails\"/>
    <add key="Mail Supervisor Mesa" value="adminsae@desarrollo_sae.org"/>
    <add key="Mail Administrador Contrato" value="adminsae@desarrollo_sae.org"/>
    <add key="HostVariable" value="1"/>
    <add key="Url_Sitio_Externo" value="http://192.168.4.144/sae_codelco/"/>
    <add key="Url_Sitio" value="http://localhost/sae_codelco/"/>
    <add key="ipExterna" value="200.27.57.180"/>
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryLogon" value="0"/>
    <add key="strDomain" value="MOSAQ"/>
    <add key="pathLDAP" value="LDAP://mosaq.local.cl/DC=mosaq,dc=local,dc=cl"/>
    <add key="PathMapaSitioDisco" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\imagenes\mapas\"/>
    <add key="PathMapaSitios" value="../../imagenes/mapas/"/>
    <add key="IPReportes" value="200.27.164.74/ReportServer$CODELCO/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/reportes_codelco/"/>
    <add key="EspecialidadEjecutivosCRM" value="14"/>
    <add key="HabilitaGenerica1Ticket" value="0"/>
    <add key="Evento Retiro Componente" value="11169"/>
    <add key="Evento Entrega Componente" value="11170"/>
    <add key="Evento Actualizacion Componente" value="11171"/>
    <add key="MisTicketsMuestraTpoRemanenteInferior" value="0"/>
    <add key="MisTicketsMuestraTpoRemanenteSuperior" value="0"/>
    <add key="MisTicketsMuestraCriticidad" value="0"/>
    <add key="Agregar_Solucion_En_Solucion_En_Linea" value="1"/>
    <add key="Id_menu_Tickets_Generales" value="132"/>
    <add key="Ver_Todas_las_Criticidades" value="1"/>
    <add key="Evento_Limpia_Password_Intranet" value="506"/>
    <add key="Solucion_Limpia_Password_Intranet" value="128"/>
    <add key="Template" value="default"/>
    <!-- banca - cobre - default - amsa-->
    <add key="RptCalidadVerCumpleSup" value="0"/>
    <add key="ObsEsperaClienteTicket" value="0"/>
    <add key="idCatGeneralDocs" value="0"/>
    <add key="pathCMDBModelos" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\CMDB\"/>
    <add key="pathDocsInst" value="E:\data\Projects\mosaq\SAE_CODELCO\SAE_CODELCO\Sitio\Instalaciones_ci\Docs\"/>
    <add key="IdCriticidadPersonaNormal" value="1"/>
    <add key="BusquedaIniIngresoOT" value="0"/>
    <!-- 0.- Usuario / 1.-RUT / 2.-CI -->
    <add key="VerResueltosListaPend" value="1"/>
    <add key="UrlSitioProyectos" value="http://localhost/sae_codelco/"/>
    <add key="CierreOT" value="1"/>
    <add key="IPExternoReportes" value="200.27.57.180:8080"/>
    <add key="pathDocumentosProyectos" value=""/>
    <add key="IngresaNegocioEnOT" value="0"/>
    <add key="BloquearModificayELiminaNotas" value="1"/>
    <add key="IncluirCodigoenLabelRut" value="0"/>
    <add key="MisTicketsMuestraComponentes" value="0"/>
    <add key="MisTicketsMuestraRegion" value="1"/>
    <add key="encuestaDinamicaBasica" value="0"/>
    <add key="encuestaDinamicaAvanzada" value="0"/>
    <!--
        - AdmiteCreacionPersonas: 0-Deshabilitado para todos
                                  1-Habilitado para los Id's de Empresas especificados en AdmiteCreacionPersonasIdEmpresas.
        - AdmiteCreacionPersonasIdEmpresas: ID's DE EMPRESAS SEPARADAS POR ',' SI SE DEJA VACIO O UN CERO SIGNIFICA QUE ESTA HABILITADO PARA TODAS LAS EMPRESAS
         -->
    <add key="AdmiteCreacionPersonas" value="1"/>
    <add key="AdmiteCreacionPersonasIdEmpresas" value=""/>
    <add key="IdMedioAtencionTareaAgenda" value="4"/>
    <add key="IdEncuestaReclamoTarea" value="2"/>
    <add key="IdEncuestaFelicitacionesTarea" value="1"/>
    <add key="IdEncuestaReclamoProceso" value="0"/>
    <add key="IdEncuestaFelicitacionesProceso" value="0"/>
    <add key="ResolverPorEmail" value="0"/>
    <add key="idEvtoReposAlta" value="1"/>
    <!--ID EVENTO CATALOGO REPOSICIO ALTA-MEDIA-->
    <add key="idEvtoReposBaja" value="2"/>
    <!--ID EVENTO CATALOGO REPOSICIO BAJA-->
    <add key="EmpresasRecatalogar" value="2,3,4,5"/>
    <add key="UtilizaCorrecionFechaComprometida" value="0"/>
    <add key="ModCriticidadEnOT" value="1"/>
    <add key="UsaReglaFechasAmsa" value="0"/>
    <!-- 0.- No / 1.- Si - OJO, SOLO PARA AMSA-->
    <add key="AtentoMisTicketsResaltaMasivo" value="1"/>
    <!-- 0.- No / 1.- Si -->
    <add key="Cliente" value="Atento"/>
    <add key="LlamadaRapidaN1N2N3" value="3,10,Consulta"/>
    <add key="LlamadaRapidaIDEvento" value="11392"/>
    <add key="urlSitioNoticias" value="http://www.saedemo.cl/noticias/default.aspx?rawHsh="/>
    <add key="solicIdEstado" value="1"/>
    <add key="IdMedioAtencionSolContacto" value="5"/>
    <add key="solicIdTipo" value="3"/>
    <add key="idGenericoSolicitantePGFensaMademsa" value="1"/>
    <add key="IDTGenjunaeb" value="221"/>
    <add key="IDTGenmademsa" value="220"/>
    <add key="IDTGenfensa" value="219"/>
    <!-- Nueva funcionalidad cuando la empresa no me provee el login de la persona hay que buscarla por rut-->
    <add key="SearchByDescriptionInActive" value="0"/>
    <add key="SearchActiveUserName" value="Prueba"/>
    <add key="SearchActiveUserPassword" value="12345678"/>
    <!-- *************************************************-->
    <add key="junaeb" value="0"/>
    <!-- Solo si es junaeb dejar en 1 -->
    <add key="gruposCAS" value="1"/>
    <!-- Solo si es cas dejar en 1 -->
    <add key="bpm2009" value="0"/>
    <add key="url_bpm2009" value="http://ignacio-pc/websaeprocesos2009/paginas/ticket_proceso.aspx"/>
    <add key="SaeV2MDB.WSProcesos2009.WsInstansiaProceso" value="http://ignacio-pc/WSSAEProcesos2009/WsInstansiaProceso.asmx"/>
    <add key="urlReporteContratosPagos" value="http://192.168.4.73/ReportServer$CODELCO/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2freportes_codelco%2fEstado_de_pago"/>
    <add key="url_rfc" value="http://localhost/sae_codelco_rfc/default.aspx"/>
    <add key="IdMedioAtencionDefectoOT" value="2"/>
    <add key="IdTipoCatalogoDefectoOT" value="1"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ajax/*.ashx_POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" verb="POST,GET" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory, Ajax" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the preCondition attribute from the web.config handler. now it works again

Answer (score 0):

Set the managed pipeline mode for the app pool it runs under to 'Classic'